# How to deal with groups when splitting a data into train and test?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, categorical-data, dataset, train-test-split

Say i have a dataset with groups that i want to use for a Regression problem that looks like the following where feature1 is the group column:

```
idx:      [0,1,2,3,4,5]

feature1: [1,1,2,2,3,3]

feature2: [6,7,8,9,4,5]

target:   [9,8,4,3,2,6]
```

How do i split this properly without any data leakage? Ive read that you need to split the data by groups such that the groups in train do not appear in test. But doesnt that mean that if i use the group feature as a categorical feature, then that feature in the test set will be completely unseen? How do i tackle this problem? Can i split the data randomly?

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading about this topic and consulted some advisors, and have come to the conclusion that it depends on your goals and the data structure.

The most common case is that you want to build a model and test its predictive power for new data, and in this case, you take 20% of the whole dataset across all groups. For example, if you have 5 scores each from 10 students per classroom A-J, you wouldn't allocate whole classrooms to the test dataset as "classroom" is a variable that will likely influence scores. This would decrease the predictive power of your modeling as whole classrooms were removed from training data, so testing and training datasets should contain data from all classrooms A-J. But, to avoid data leakage, all of a student's test scores should be allocated to *either* the test or train dataset. So for 80/20 training/testing datasets, scores from two students in each classroom should be allocated to a test dataset.

It might make sense to remove whole classrooms for a test dataset if you specifically wanted to test whether your model could accurately predict student scores in a new classroom, but this will be influenced by which classroom is set aside for the test dataset, and whether there were similar classrooms in the training data.